# Как в phpstorm вернуть плюсики/минусы и список файлов вверху?

Tags: phpstorm

Как в phpstorm вернуть плюсики/минусы и список файлов вверху?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Список файлов, он же Tabs: Editor > General > Editor Tabs, выбираете *Placement*
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Плюсы и минусы, они же Code Folding: Editor > General > Code Folding, включаете *Show code folding outline*
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]